# React Hooks- forEach of an array doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working in a project using React hooks. However I try to use a variable without useState hook to handle a variable. The thing is that when I'm running a function that contains an array operation, it seems like that is not took into account and skip that step.
I did the change that way (you'll see that soon in the code) because I'm using an array that is continuos adding more values, so I think that is easier to do in that way.

Can you please help me to fix that issue or explain me why is that doesn't working?

Here is the code:

```
    let platosRegVent:any = [];                           // This is how I'm declaring my array

const agregarPlato = async () => {
    if(validarCamposPlato()){
        try{
            let valorParcial = 0;
            let platoExist = await encontrarPlato(config, rvPlato);
            if(platoExist === true){
                setAgregadoMin(true);
                platoCodigo = await obtenerCodigoPlato(config, rvPlato);                    
                platosRegVent.push({codigoPlato: platoCodigo, cantidad: rvCantidad});           // Here is where I'm adding more objects to my array.
                let costoPlato = await obtenerValorPlato(config, rvPlato);
                valorParcial = valorTotal;
                setValorTotal(valorParcial += (costoPlato * parseInt(rvCantidad)));
                setRvPlato('');
                setRvCantidad('');
            }
            else{
                toast.error('El plato ingresado no se ha encontrado.');
                setRvPlato('');
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            toast.error('Un error inesperado ha ocurrido, por favor intente mas tarde.');
            props.handleSubmit();
        }
    }
}
const finalizarRegVent = async () => {
    console.log(agregadoMin);
    if(validarCampos()){  
        try{
            if(rvPlato !== '' || rvCantidad !== ''){
                await agregarPlato();
            }
            if(agregadoMin === true){
                rvCodigo = await crearRegistroVenta(config, valorTotal, fechaActual, regVentMesa);

                platosRegVent.forEach( (plato : any) => {                      //Here is the operation of the array. It seems that this step is skipped.
                    crearRegVentPlato(config, rvCodigo, plato.codigoPlato, plato.cantidad);
                });

               setValorFinal(false);

            }
            else{
                toast.error('Debe ingresar por lo menos un plato para completar el registro.');
            }  
        }
        catch(error){
            toast.error('Un error inesperado ha ocurrido, por favor intente mas tarde.');
            props.handleSubmit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `platosRegVent` contains all of the items you are expecting?

Comment: Yes... as you can see in the push of the array, I'm creating the objects with those fields. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use useState() & useCallback() hook instead.
Because the mechanism of React only updated when detecting the change of state. If you create static variable, react can't update its value.
Alternatively, useRef() is solution for you.